# How can I access to all component of a certain type in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity

I want access to (for example) all AudioSources in Unity and stop all sounds.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class StopAllSound: MonoBehaviour {

    void Start() {
        AudioSource[] allMyAudioSources = GetComponents<AudioSource>();
        allMyAudioSources.Stop();
    }
}
```

This does not work, because of the followin error:

```
Assets/SlowMotion.cs(8,35): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.AudioSource[]' does not contain a definition for `Stop' and no extension method `Stop' of type `UnityEngine.AudioSource[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I try it by FindObjectsOfType:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SlowMotion : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start() {
        AudioSource[] allAudioSources = UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType<AudioSource>();
        allAudioSources.Stop();
    }
}
```

but I get the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Array doesn't contains `Stop`. But AudioSource does. So take all AudioSources in loop and Stop them as `AudioSource` not `AudioSource[]`. Array of anything having its own attributes and methods irrespective of what type of element that array contains.

You can do that by,

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class StopAllSound: MonoBehaviour {

    void Start() {
        AudioSource[] allMyAudioSources = FindObjectsOfType<AudioSource>();
        foreach(AudioSource s in allMyAudioSources)
            s.Stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mute *all* sounds in your game, then it might be far more elegant to not mute your audio sources but mute the [`AudioListener`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioListener.html) instead. You can do this with `AudioListener.pause = true` or `AudioListener.volume = 0.0f`.